# What is the purpose of repeating prepositions?

Tags: verbs, preposition, compound-verb

In *Lingua Latina per se illustrata*, chapter 7, there are several examples of phrases where a compound verb, using a preposition as a prefix, is used in conjunction with a lone preposition:

> Quid **in**est **in** saccīs?
>   Iūlius **ad** vīllam **ad**venit.
>   Iūlia **ē** cubiculō **ex**it

What is the purpose of this repetition?  For example, in place of the second sentence, why not either of these options:

> Iūlius vīllam **ad**venit.
>   Iūlius **ad** vīllam venit.

Does a lack of repetition here make the sentence ungrammatical?  Or is the purpose emphasis, or something else?

Comment: Often a prefix changes the tone of the verb in a different way than the preposition suggests. For example, *invenire aliquid* is very different from *venire in aliquid*. Therefore the preposition and the prefix contribute to the meaning in different ways. In your examples this difference seems slight, though; the repetition is just for emphasis and redundancy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All three versions (*Július villam advenit, Július ad villam advenit,* and *Július ad villam venit*) are grammatically correct. My sense is that the latter two are more frequently found than the first, but I can't swear by that.

In *Latin Prose Through English Idiom* (1882), Edwin Abbott writes (all emphases and capitalization as in the original)

> A few general rules may be laid down about Latin Verbs *containing Prepositions and conveying a notion of motion to, or motion from* Such verbs, *e.g.* **detraho**, can be used metaphorically or literally. If we say 'princeps **detrahit** milites' we do not mean that the emperor literally himself draws away the soldiers; but in '**detrahit** anulum' the Verb is literally used. *Literal* motion must be *more emphatically expressed*. If literally used, they require *the Preposition to be repeated for emphasis*.
>
> Princeps detraxit milites imperatori.
>   Princeps detraxit anulum de digito suo.